# Point source in focal point of lens

Tags: optics, fourier-transform

I'm doing currently wave optics on lens systems. I encountered the following situation:

Placing a point source in the (object space) focalpoint of the lens should give the Fourier Transform of that point source in the image space.
We expect this since a lens acts as Fourier Transform.
The Fourier Transform of a delta function (our point source) is a constant function. This is in accordance with ray optics. ("focal rays will be parallel rays after the lens").

To describe my situation, I took equation (3.3.3) out of the book "Advanced Optical Imaging Theory" from Min Gu. $P$ is a pupil function which is $0$ for $x^2+y^2>d^2$ and $1$ otherwise. $\sigma$ is our field at the object space focal plane. $U_3$ is the field at the image space focal plane. The other variables should be clear.

$$U_3(x_3,y_3) = \frac{\exp(-2ikf)}{f^2\lambda^2}\int \int \int \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} P(x_2,y_2) \sigma(x_1,y_1) \exp\left(\frac{ik(x_2^2+y_2^2}{2f} \right) \exp\left( \frac{-ik((x_2-x_1)^2+(y_2-y_1)^2)}{2f}  \right) \exp\left( \frac{-ik((x_3-x_2)^2+(y_3-y_2)^2)}{2f} \right) \mathrm{d}x_1 \mathrm{d}y_1 \mathrm{d}x_2 \mathrm{d} y_2  $$

(To readers of the book: I changed a few things $d_1$ etc.).
To have a point source we can set $\sigma(x_1,y_2)=\delta(x_1,y_2)$ which removes us one integral:

$$U_3(x_3,y_3) = \frac{\exp(-2ikf)}{f^2\lambda^2} \int \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}  P(x_2,y_2)  \exp\left( \frac{-ik((x_3-x_2)^2+(y_3-y_2)^2)}{2f} \right) \mathrm{d}x_2 \mathrm{d} y_2 $$

We can take one constant phase factor out of the integral an get:
$$U_3(x_3,y_3) = \frac{\exp(-2ikf)}{f^2\lambda^2} \exp\left(-\frac{ik(x_3^2+y_3^2)}{2f} \right)\int \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}  P(x_2,y_2)  \exp\left( \frac{ik(x_2 x_3+y_2 y_3))}{2f} \right) \exp\left( \frac{-ik(x_2^2+y_2^2)}{2f} \right) \mathrm{d}x_2 \mathrm{d} y_2 $$

We can switch to polar coordinates and remove therefore the pupil function $P$.
$$U_3(x_3,y_3) = \frac{\exp(-2ikf)}{f^2\lambda^2} \exp\left(-\frac{ik(x_3^2+y_3^2)}{2f} \right)\int_0^{2\pi} \int_{0}^{d}    \exp\left( \frac{ikr( x_3 \cos\varphi +y_3 \sin\varphi ))}{2f} \right) \exp\left( \frac{-ikr^2}{2f} \right) r \mathrm{d}r \mathrm{d} \varphi $$

Now we can remove the integral over $\varphi$ with the Bessel function:
$$U_3(x_3,y_3) = \frac{\exp(-2ikf)}{f^2\lambda^2} \exp\left(\frac{-ik(x_3^2+y_3^2)}{2f} \right) \int_{0}^{d}  J_0\left(kr\sqrt{x_3^2+y_3^2}\right) \exp\left( \frac{-ikr^2}{2f} \right) r \mathrm{d}r $$

I would except out of the fourier properties of the lens that this integral should be constant. But a quick-and-dirty mathematica calculation gives me something different. (I also did a matlab implementation)

To the end my question is: Why is the results not constant as predicted from the Fourier Transform properties of our lens?

I would be really thankful if somebody could help me!

Felix

[image: Numerical Evaluation of the last integral]

Comment: Why do you expect the Fourier transform of the circular pupil to have constant modulus?

Comment: I would excpect that the Fourier Transform of the delta peak has constant modulus since I place the delta peak at the front focal plane and want to observe the intensity at the back focal plane of the lens.

Comment: but the "lens" is restricted by the  pupil, so it is not just a quadratic phase transformer, the lens-pupil combination is also a low-pass filter, hence the "ripples".

Comment: So what I did seems to be correct? 
If we choose $d$ quite large then the "ripples" should disappear and we see our constant profile?

Comment: if you make d larger the ripples do not disappear, moreover the height of the ripples stay the same but they do crowd closer to the main lobe that will also narrow; check out the "Gibbs phenomenon"

Comment: But for an infinite lens we should have the fourier transform property which delivers a constant result?